# Installing Windows7 On Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: windows

Im going to make a Windows 7 Live usb right now, But Im wondering how can I just install windows 7? I dont want ubuntu anymore . Thanks

Comment: You should make use of 'Search' feature at least once.
Anyway here's a thread about the same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on You should make a separate question if either you are having some sort of difficulty in it or want to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You choice is illogical...

Why should you go back to windows?!

ubuntu w

- ill run faster.
- ubuntu is free
- you can always change your mind and pay for windows, but ubuntu is free so does it really hurt to try?
- automatically works with printers and most hardware; windows does not.
- has free software including office program, playing music, internet
  browsers

Anyway  Check [this](http://techluminati.com/operating-systems/linux-vs-windows/)  and [this](http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-13-10-a-desktop-tour-slideshow-7000021826/) to be sure of your choice...

The [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) in the answer above is a good tutorial to do that

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have a windows ISO file ?
then using this article you will be able to make a bootable USB.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

then restart your lappy. you will get an option to install windows. 
This is a fresh install of windows.